# Test charge and source charge test for EM field strength

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, wavefunction

We know how to determine the strength/density of an electric/magnetic field by placing a test charge in the source charge's electric field and then measuring the force the test charge experiences. How do we measure the force that the test charge experiences in the field? And we somehow know the distance that the test charge is from the source charge, but how? Do we measure the position of the test charge and source charge during this experiment?

Do we collapse the wave functions of the source and test charges during this experiment?

Comment: Please, if you vote down, explain why.

Comment: classically, I think they do it by measuring the acceleration of the test charge instead. quantumly, I am not so sure (probably quite different story, you will have to do things like scattering on the test charge?).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the test charge is hypothetical rather than practical. Its purpose is to illustrate what electric field strength means.

But you can measure the force on a test charge if you want, using a force meter or a beam balance. In the [Coulomb Experiment](http://people.physics.tamu.edu/mcintyre/courses/phys208H/labs/Lab_1.pdf) a torsion balance is used.

If you want to verify the formula for the Coulomb force $F=kQ_1Q_2/r^2$ you also have to measure the distance between the point charges. But if you only want to measure the electric field strength $E$ at the position of the test charge, all you need to know is the force $F$ on the test charge $Q$, then $E=F/Q$.

Comment: How do we measure the distance between point charges? Does this collapse the wave function of the particles?

Comment: How does the wavefunction come into this? Is this a question about classical electrostatics, or quantum physics? The test charge does not have to be an electron. Trying to measure the electric force between two electrons would not be practical.

Comment: quantum physics. Don't we do these experiments with subatomic particles? The experiment that I mentioned in the question, and the coulomb experiment ?

Comment: The main charge and the test charge contain a surplus or deficit of electrons (in very large numbers), but there is no quantum physics involved. This is a classical physics experiment.

Comment: Have we ever done the test charge experiment with just single subatomic particles?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.